# Signup Error only with Android 6 version

Tags: android

Building an android app.  I have a signup where the app collects user's personal info (image, name, dob, gender, email, password, mobile#) in 4 screens.  The problem I am facing is that the phones with Android 6 ends up with "Server communication error".  But the new id is created.  All other android versions work fine except version 6.  Any idea what to check or solution?  Thank you.

Comment: No idea without seeing your code.

Comment: Post your code @tabb

Comment: You might want to check your android permissions, as of android 6, having your permissions in the manifest is not enough, you need to request them from the user at run time and check if its been granted before you use anything that needs them, Also post your code so we can better help you

Comment: Thank you very much for tips.